# Cuda with Conda installation - libcuda.so.1 not found

Tags: centos, nvidia, datascience-anaconda, cudnn

I've been trying to install CONDA with Cuda in Centos 7. I am following this [installation](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc). When I go through with the install I get no errors thrown until I try to import tensorflow in the environment. When I do, the following stack-trace accompanies a failure to import:

```
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
**ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

The error is the inability to access the libcuda.so.1 resource. Am I incorrect in thinking that Conda handles all aspects of the installation?

System details:

OS: Centos7

Kernel Version: 3.10.0

Cuda version: 10.0

Conda version: 4.6.14

GPU: Nvidia 1080Ti

Comment: You need the lib64 directory of your cuda installation added to LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you point me to some documentation for that?

Comment: @mkc can you provide further clarification? Which path do I export this to?

Comment: Look up the web on how to export environment variables and LD_LIBRARY_PATH; then find where is the lib64 directory of your cuda installation. Then put that directory's path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and export it.